# Lineheight in HTMLView

Tags: react-native

Somehow this is not working for Android but works on iOS:

```
<HTMLView value={itemDetail.description} stylesheet={htmlstyle}/>

const htmlstyle = StyleSheet.create({
  p:{
    lineHeight:28,
    fontSize:16,
    color:'#444343'
  }
});
```

You can find the component here: 
https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview

The description is something like this:

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

On `Android` the color and fontSize change, but not the lineHeight. On `iOS` emulator everything works.

If there's an alternative to set the `lineheight`, please let me know.

Comment: This issue is related to the react-native-html package as it tries to convert html to native components and its not really a react-native question, please open an issue on their repo instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plugging in an Android device usb and going to `chrome://inspect/#devices` in your Chrome browser? Check the Computed Styles on the device in the inspector, that might give you some insight to what is going wrong

Or the React debugger in this case: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools

Comment: I can't see any devices there eventhough it's successfully built on my Android.

Answer (score 0):

This is working on Android in the current version (0.10).